# Using Google Apps Scripts replaceText() isn't working with the question mark

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script script that I wrote that uses:

```
paragraph.replaceText(sentences[j], edit);
```

If sentences[j] ends with a question mark, the resulting change is equivalent to

```
edit + "?"
```

For example:

```
paragraph.replaceText("How are you?", "Hello world!");
```

changes my document to "Hello World!?" instead of "Hello World!"

This only happens with question marks. I have tested it with periods, exclamation marks and ellipsis.

I have tried a few things:

- replaceText("?","stuff") and gotten invalid regular expression for the "?".
- replaceText(/\?/, "stuff") and the question marks don't change.
- replaceText(/\?\?/, "?") doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't change anything.

To create sentences I do

```
var lines = paragraph.getText().split(/\b(\?|\!|\.\.\.|\u2026|\. \. \.|\.|\n\r|\r\n|\n|\r)/g);
var sentences = [];
for(j=0;j < lines.length;j = j+2){
  sentences.push(lines[j]+lines[j+1]); 
}
```

and it catches question marks just fine. 
Anyone have any clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search pattern is passed **as a string**, not a JavaScript regular expression object. That's why your replaceText calls that start with a regular expression don't change  anything:

```
replaceText(/\?/, "stuff"); //and the question marks don't change.
replaceText(/\?\?/, "?");// doesn't throw an error, it just doesn't change anything.
```

`?` in itself is not a valid regular expression (hence the error you got).
`x?` means zero or one x, prefer one

If you don't want the `?` to have special meaning, you can escape it. This would work ...

```
paragraph.replaceText("How are you\?", "Hello world!");
```

But of course you would need to substitute inside your `sentences` array all characters that have a special meaning.

[This is a list of a all the characters that need to be escaped because they have a special meaning in Google's RE2 library.](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)